# How to send and properly consume HTML 'data-' number attribute in SCSS function

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to create a resizable `<LoadingSpinner>` component in React using an SVG element. I have the following component definition and SCSS styles:

```
// LoadingSpinner.tsx
import React from 'react'
import cx from 'classnames'

import styles from './_styles.module.scss'

type Props = {
  className?: string;
  color?: 'white' | 'blue' | '';
  colorClassName?: string;
  diameter?: number;
  strokeWidth?: number;
}

function LoadingSpinner({
  className,
  color = '',
  colorClassName,
  diameter = 50,
  strokeWidth = 3,
}: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <svg className={cx(styles.loadingSpinner, className)} width={diameter} height={diameter}>
      <circle
        className={styles.loadingCircle}
        data-r={(diameter / 2) - 5} // <--- What my question is about
        cx={diameter / 2}
        cy={diameter / 2}
        r={(diameter / 2) - 5}
        fill="none"
        stroke={cx(styles[color], colorClassName)}
        strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
      />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

```
// _styles.module.scss
@function getStrokeDashValue($radius, $percentage) {
  $circumference: 2 * 3.1415927 * $radius;
  $percentage-as-decimal: $percentage / 100%;
  @return $circumference * $percentage-as-decimal;
}

.loadingCircle {
  --circle-radius: attr(data-r number, 20); // <--- attempt to use data- value
  // ...
  stroke-dasharray: getStrokeDashValue(var(--circle-radius), 100%);
}
```

When I attempt to run the above, I get the following error output:
`SassError: Undefined operation: "6.28319 times var(--circle-radius)".` which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
:root {
  --color-black: attr(data-r number, 20);
}
.loadingCircle {
  // ...
  stroke-dasharray: getStrokeDashValue(var(--circle-radius), 100%);
}
```

this will work

Comment: No, this did not work unfortunately. Still got the same error. Don't think it was a matter of moving the CSS custom property definition from the local class to the `:root`

Comment: i think this is the issue ``attr(data-r number, 20);``` coz i dont see anything imported called attr. Import that then it will work.

Comment: No, that is not the issue -- `attr` comes from native CSS. It's not something you import.